# Web-app using JS alone..?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, node.js

What are the possibilities that i can create a web-app using JavaScript alone and nothing else..

can you provide a full stack of useful JavaScript libraries and tools..?

Comment: may i know why i got a -1 for my question?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931645/ (disclaimer: that is my own question)

Comment: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful. I copy the title of "down vote"(-1).

Comment: no research effort, even in presence of A VAST AMOUNT of information available through any search engine of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Route 1 : Server-side JavaScript**

[`node.js`](http://nodejs.org/) is server-side JavaScript. It's still young but it's great and perfectly usable. And if you've got a non-critical project I would recommend using it.

[Here's a list of js libraries I use for node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241934/nodejs-and-socket-io-is-it-pure-javascript/6242703#6242703).

**Problems with Route 1** Lack of maturity, Lack of stress testing, Lack of detailed and expansive documentation / books / tutorials (docs/tutorials exist but there not at the level that PHP or ASP.NET is at).

**Route 2 : Databases that expose themself through REST**

[couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/) has a REST API for database interaction by default. This means you can just set up your couch server and do database manipulation directly through client-side ajax calls. (You will need some kind of static file server).

There are plenty of tools like [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) to make pure client side development manageable.

**Problems with Route 2** Difficult to deal with security, difficult to deal with validation.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS is one. But you might need to us AJAX

Comment: what about nodejs and sproutcore ? I just need a full operational stack to work on ....

Comment: ExtJS is a client side framework, express is a server side library

Comment: @Raynos: Yes, I focussed on the client-side part more

Comment: @sudimail but you forgot to mention that using express on the client is very silly.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, although rather difficult. Have a look at [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/), I guess it's an example of an application you might be interested in looking at.